# Illegal Forward Reference while printing but not while assigning the value

Tags: java, variables, printing, static

In the below snippet, if I would remove the `print()` statement, the code works fine. But if I add the print statement, it generates an Illegal forward reference error. If that is because the variable `a` is declared after the static block, then why is it permitting to assign the value. Even that statement `a = 20` should also raise the same error. Right?

```
public class Test {
    static {
        a = 20;
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    static int a = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) is worded in a way to specifically allow static fields that are declared later in textual order to appear in the LHS of assignment in a static initialiser _before the declaration_. Does that answer your question, or do you want to know the rationale behind this?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, that did answer my question. It shall be great if you can share some insights about the same.

Comment: Also can you please look into this question, @Sweeper. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64645494/in-which-part-of-memory-the-static-methods-are-stored-in-java-how-is-it-differ

Answer (score 2):

The JLS has [a specific list of the forward references that are disallowed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3); your print statement falls foul of the restrictions. The assignment `a = 20` is not disallowed because it doesn't match

> The reference is *not* on the left hand side of an assignment expression

In essence, the restrictions say that you can't use a forward reference that "observes" the variable's value in cases where the value might not be defined. The fact that it is definitely assigned in this case might arguably be a reason for allowing the reference in a future revision, but for now it matches the ban.